# Using pymongo/mongodb to filter based on multiple conditions including and/or?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using the pymongo tutorial with the restaurant's database in a Zeppelin notebook.

1. Which of the restaurants are pizzerias and have at
   a grade lower than C or a score greater than
   19, regardless of grade?

I have tried using both $or/$and statements but I keep getting an error

```
%mongodb

db.resturants.find({$and :[{"cuisine": {$regex: "Pizza"}},
                           {"grades.grade" : {$ne: "A"}},
                           {"grades.grade" : {$ne: "B"}},
                           {"grades.grade" : {$ne: "C"}}]},
                   {$or : [{"cuisine": {$regex: "Pizza"}},
                           {"grades.score" : {$gt: 19}}]}).table()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strings for your operators:

```
db.resturants.find({"$and" :[{"cuisine": {$regex: "Pizza"}},
                           {"grades.grade" : {$ne: "A"}},
                           {"grades.grade" : {$ne: "B"}},
                           {"grades.grade" : {$ne: "C"}}]},
                   {"$or" : [{"cuisine": {$regex: "Pizza"}},
                           {"grades.score" : {$gt: 19}}]}).table()
```

Your syntax is valid in MongoDB but pymongo has to work with strings.

Comment: this doesn't provide any output. If only including the $and statement without quotes it works, but adding in quotes to $and causes it to no longer output anything